# MYSQL json_object with 1 child and child is combined with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, json, tree

Im looking for an answer how to merge/union/etc. 2 tables inside the same child within the JSON_Object.

I have 3 tables.

- modules
- data_fields (child of Modules by modu_id)
- reports (child of modules by modu_id)

```
CREATE TABLE modules (
  modu_id INT,
  appli_id INT,
  modu_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_modu_links INT
  
);
INSERT INTO modules VALUES (1,1,"Module 1",5);
INSERT INTO modules VALUES (2,1,"Module 2",6);

CREATE TABLE applications (
  appli_id INT,
  appli_title VARCHAR(50)
  
);
INSERT INTO applications VALUES (1,"application 1");
INSERT INTO applications VALUES (2,"application 2");

CREATE table data_fields (
  data_id INT,
  modu_id INT,
  data_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_data_links INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(1,1,"Data field 1",1);
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(2,2,"Data field 2",2);
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(3,2,"Data field 3",1);

CREATE table reports (
  repo_id INT,
  modu_id INT,
  repo_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_repo_links INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(1,1,"report 1",1);
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(2,2,"report 2",2);
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(3,2,"report 3",1);

SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

I would like to get the following response.

```
{
    "modu_id": 1,
    "modu_title": "Module 1",
    "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "data field 1",
                "t_links": 1,
                "datatype": "datafield"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "report 1"
                "t_links": 1,
                "datatype": "report"
            }
            ]
},
{
    "modu_id": 2,
    "modu_title": "Module 2",
    "data": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "data field 2",
                "t_links": 2,
                "datatype": "datafield"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "data field 3",
                "t_links": 1,
                "datatype": "datafield"
            }
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "report 2"
                "t_links": 1,
                "datatype": "report"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "report 3"
                "t_links": 1,
                "datatype": "report"
            }
            ]
}
```

I know I have to create 2 subqueries to get the results but im stuggeling to get the 2 tables into 1 json_object.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT
    m.appli_id,
    a.appli_title,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "modu_id", m.modu_id,
        "modu_title", m.modu_title,
        "data", datafields)) as datafields,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "modu_id", m.modu_id,
        "modu_title", m.modu_title,
        "data", reports)) as reports,
    JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "modu_id", m.modu_id,
        "modu_title", m.modu_title,
        "data", datafields)),
        '$.data', 
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "modu_id", m.modu_id,
        "modu_title", m.modu_title,
        "data", reports)))
FROM
(SELECT
    m.appli_id,
    m.modu_id,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "id", d.data_id,
        "title", d.data_title,
        "t_links", d.t_data_links,
        "Fieldtype", "datafield"
        )) as datafields
FROM modules as m
LEFT JOIN data_fields as d ON m.modu_id = d.modu_id
WHERE m.appli_id = 1
GROUP BY m.appli_id, m.modu_id
) as datafields

,
(SELECT
    m.appli_id,
    m.modu_id,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        "id", r.repo_id,
        "title", r.repo_title,
        "t_links", r.t_repo_links,
        "Fieldtype", "report"
        )) as reports
FROM modules as m
LEFT JOIN reports as r ON m.modu_id = r.modu_id
WHERE m.appli_id = 1
GROUP BY m.appli_id, m.modu_id
) as reports
JOIN modules m USING(modu_id)
JOIN applications a ON a.appli_id = m.appli_id

GROUP BY m.appli_id
```

I know this code is not correct because it gives me double the records.

Hopefully you guys can help me.

Comment: without and tables and data that would produce that result, we can't help you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk, what part of the information are you missing? I did give an example with data.

Comment: as described in the Link CREATE TABLE for LL Tbles involved , INSERT INTO for all tables , ideally you make a dbfiddle

Comment: I understand now, i will edit the question.

Comment: that isn't enough  see https://dbfiddle.uk/mfLUZ8Vz

Comment: Made some changes and it should work now. I still get an error in the dbfiddle but in MYSQL it works.
"Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.appli_title' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: Yes your code is not clean please provide always the working dbfiddle link

Comment: its clean now :) it should work now.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Gt2tn2Cblb

Comment: that is empty and use my dbfiddle link like is said only _fiull_Group_by is really necessary to get deterministic, your link is also empty

Comment: @nbk, the code works in de link I provided. somehow your link says "run failed". 
Can you copy the data to my link?
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oPbiRYqFjfVwNTAZryvCw6/2

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem that you have is that two subselcts are cross joined,

Removing the coma separated join and using proper JOIN which are 30 years already SQL standard

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE modules (
  modu_id INT,
  appli_id INT,
  modu_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_modu_links INT
  
);
INSERT INTO modules VALUES (1,1,"Module 1",5);
INSERT INTO modules VALUES (2,1,"Module 2",6);

CREATE TABLE applications (
  appli_id INT,
  appli_title VARCHAR(50)
  
);
INSERT INTO applications VALUES (1,"application 1");
INSERT INTO applications VALUES (2,"application 2");

CREATE table data_fields (
  data_id INT,
  modu_id INT,
  data_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_data_links INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(1,1,"Data field 1",1);
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(2,2,"Data field 2",2);
INSERT INTO data_fields VALUES(3,2,"Data field 3",1);

CREATE table reports (
  repo_id INT,
  modu_id INT,
  repo_title VARCHAR(50),
  t_repo_links INT
  );
  
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(1,1,"report 1",1);
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(2,2,"report 2",2);
INSERT INTO reports VALUES(3,2,"report 3",1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    m.appli_id,
    a.appli_title,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('modu_id',
                    m.modu_id,
                    'modu_title',
                    m.modu_title,
                    'data',
                    datafields)) AS datafields,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('modu_id',
                    m.modu_id,
                    'modu_title',
                    m.modu_title,
                    'data',
                    reports)) AS reports,
    JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('modu_id',
                            m.modu_id,
                            'modu_title',
                            m.modu_title,
                            'data',
                            datafields)),
            '$.data',
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('modu_id',
                            m.modu_id,
                            'modu_title',
                            m.modu_title,
                            'data',
                            reports)))
FROM
    (SELECT 
        m.appli_id,
            m.modu_id,
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', d.data_id, 'title', d.data_title, 't_links', d.t_data_links, 'Fieldtype', 'datafield')) AS datafields
    FROM
        modules AS m
    LEFT JOIN data_fields AS d ON m.modu_id = d.modu_id
    WHERE
        m.appli_id = 1
    GROUP BY m.appli_id , m.modu_id) AS datafields
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        m.appli_id,
            m.modu_id,
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', r.repo_id, 'title', r.repo_title, 't_links', r.t_repo_links, 'Fieldtype', 'report')) AS reports
    FROM
        modules AS m
    LEFT JOIN reports AS r ON m.modu_id = r.modu_id
    WHERE
        m.appli_id = 1
    GROUP BY m.appli_id , m.modu_id) AS reports on datafields.appli_id = reports.appli_id 
    AND datafields.modu_id = reports.modu_id
        JOIN
    modules m ON m.modu_id = reports.modu_id
        JOIN
    applications a ON a.appli_id = m.appli_id
GROUP BY m.appli_id , a.appli_title;
```

### [image]

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oPbiRYqFjfVwNTAZryvCw6/3)

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not what im looking for. I tried this before but it gives me 2 data objects. I want to have 1 data object with data_fields and reports inside of it. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: then you must explain how the result should look like for all three columns

Comment: I did add the response i would like to get. see 2nd code block in question. thats the response i would like to get in one of the columns.